# How to run specific test cases in each describe function in mocha

Tags: mocha.js

I have many test spec files with `describe()` and `it()`. Needs to run only some cases (`it()`) say that is sanity cases of each spec file. How to run all sanity cases of each `describe()` of all test spec files?

I am using Webdriverio and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it.

1. Create separate files for each type of tests and run them as per your needs.
2. You can utilize `grep` flag of mocha to tell mocha which test case to pick.

I would prefer second one as it is more extensible. Here is what you have to do:

1. Update summary of `it` blocks to include a pattern e.g. @sanity@regression etc
2. At the tile of running tests from command line, pass grep flag as

`mocha -g "@sanity"`

Mocha will check for the text passed in the command in each of the tests and will execute only the matching ones.